# SQL Statement with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following Query:

`SELECT a.name_f, a.uid, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, b.position FROM users a  groups_members b, WHERE a.uid = b.userid AND b.group_id=$group_var`

This works great and brings back all of the users' info as well as their positions within the group for any certain group that I want to call. When a group attends an event, on that event page I want to call the above function but also an extra statement that finds whether that user is confirmed. So I run the following query:

`SELECT a.name_f, a.uid, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, b.position, c.confirmed FROM users a  groups_members b, event_users c WHERE a.uid = b.userid AND b.group_id='$group_var' and c.event_id ='$event_var' and a.uid = c.userid`

This also works great but here's where my problem arises. Let's assume that a certain group has created an event and subsequently, all of the users have been dumped into the event_users table. My 2nd query would still work and show every user in that group as well as his or her and confirmed setting but when a new user joins the group and selects his or her position, that new user is not returned in my second query and therefore, the event that shows all of the users' along with their position, does not account for any new users that were added after the event was created.

I hope that doesn't sound too confusing. Here are my tables:

```
event_users || id, event_id, userid, confirmed    

groups_members || id, userid, group_id, position

users || uid, name_f, name_l, profile
```

My question is how can I basically collect all of the current group members and subsequently if they have been entered into the event_users table, what is their confirmed status. I do not want to run queries on my group page that accounts for new users and puts them into any events that the group has

Comment: I am a little confused. Do you want to automatically add a user to an event if a user joins a group that created an event? If so it seems you could create a table of group/event pairs and when you add a user to a group, see if that group has created any events and if so add the user to the event. Or do you want users who joined a group late to show up as an unconfirmed event user? Doing this seems sketchy because it does not actually reflect the data.

Comment: No, I want to select the group members that are part of the group. My problem is when I run the query that needs the confirmed data, only users who were added to the event table when the event was first created are returned. Users that joined the group after the event was created won't be returned and I can't alter the event table to account for new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left joins:

```
    SELECT 
      a.name_f, a.uid, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, b.position, c.confirmed 
    FROM users a 
    JOIN groups_members b on a.uid = b.userid
    LEFT JOIN event_users c on a.uid = c.userid
    WHERE b.group_id='$group_var' and c.event_id ='$event_var'
```

You will be getting NULL as a value of c.confirmed if there is no correspondent record in event_users table. You may use coalesce() function to put there default value:

```
     coalesce(c.confirmed, 0)
```

or

```
     coalesce(c.confirmed, 'not subscribed yet')
```

Comment: Hi barbalion, I'm still only getting the users who were already in the event users table returned and not all of the group members.

Comment: Oops, my fault. This actually did the trick. I was manually over-riding some table data and cause it not to work previously. Thanks again!